# Ionic - Routerlink not triggering Lifecycle events

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router-dom, ionic-react

I'm struggling with Ionic's lifecycle events used with RouterLink.

I have my app data in a JSON file that renders each item using the url paramenters when the page is loaded. I need buttons to go to the next or previous item and refresh the page content, ie:

- I'm on Item 1 (/lecture/item1) => click next => routerLink(/lecture/item2)
- I'm on Item 1 (/lecture/item1) => click prev => routerLink(/lecture/item0)
  That means that each time i move to a page i need to get the params from the url (`/lecture/:param`) and update the page data.
  The problem i'm facing is that RouterLink isn't triggering any Page Leaving lifecycle, so my states doesn't change, also, i can't clean the states (i can do it through an href param, but the whole app is refreshed).
  I found similar threads on this, but some of them are outdated/still opened:
  [Routerlink bug github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20597#issuecomment-669013820).

Is there any way/workaround to reload the component and update the states passing different parameters?

I already tried using useHistory hook, history.replace [(Source)](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20543), and routerDirection="back" but none of them are triggering ion page leaving hooks. I also tried replacing IonRouterOutlet with Switch but this means not having some important ionic features.

Thank you in advance!!

Here is an extract of code for reference:

lectures.json (Array of objects)

```
{
    "list" : [ {}  ]
}
```

App.tsx

```
<IonApp>      
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
          <Menu />
          
          <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Redirect to="/lectures" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/lectures" exact component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/lectures/:name" exact>
              <Lecture />
            </Route>
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonSplitPane>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
```

Lecture.tsx

```
const Page: React.FC = () => {

  const [lecturaIndex, setLecturaIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [btnLinks, setBtnLinks] = useState<{next?: string , prev?: string }>({});

 useIonViewDidEnter(()=>{
    // Gets page params and use them to find current item in data json
    let current;
    current = lectures.list.find(lecture => lecture.title === match.params.name); 
    setLecturaIndex(current.id);
   // Set next and prev buttons url for routerLink
    setBtnLinks({
      next: current.id < 13 ? `/lectures/${languages.list[current.id+1].title}` : '/lectures', 
      prev: current.id > 0 ? `/lectures/${languages.list[current.id-1].title}` : '/lectures'
    });
   // function that Enables/disables navigation buttons depending on current index. ie: if i=0; can't go back
    indexCheck(current);
  })

// THESE ARE NEVER TRIGGERED WHEN GOING TO NEXT PARAM (/lectures/:param)
useIonViewWillLeave(()=>{
    console.log('will leave lecture');
  })

  useIonViewDidLeave(()=>{
    console.log('did leave lecture');
  })
  return(
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>        
        <IonButton          
          disabled={nextBtnDisable}           
          routerLink={btnLinks.next}
          routerDirection="back"      
          >
        NEXT
        </IonButton>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  )
}
```

Comment: I can't speak to the ionic framework, but normally a `useEffect` with dependency on the route match param is sufficient for issuing side-effects like refetching relevant data.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks! that could work, i'm going to try that approach and post an update, however, i would prefer using Ionic lifecycle hooks since they give extra/more precise functionalities inside an Ionic app, deps can be passed to it, so it could work!

Comment: just use history to navigate between the pages if there is a bug in routerLink?

Comment: I tried @DrewReese 's solution and it worked! However i had a bug and was able to make it not appear anymore but i dont have a clue how it fixed . I added [match.params] as dependency When navigating between next/prev /lectures/:param (same component), it works but when navigating to another url (ie root  '/') (other component) it throws an error ('cant find param of null '). However if i use an arrow fn it seems to work ok! [() => Match.params]. Why is this happening?

Comment: `() => Match.params` is a new function reference each render cycle, so if used as a hook dependency will trigger the hook's callback each render cycle.

Comment: Ah, I see, just did some reading up on these ionic hooks [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/lifecycle#guidance-for-each-lifecycle-method) and I see that `ionViewWillEnter` and `ionViewDidEnter` are basically mounting lifecycle hooks, and don't seem like they'd trigger if you're already on a view and only changing URL path parameters. The `useEffect` is also called when mounting, and again when any specified dependencies update. If `match` is sometimes undefined then you may be able to use Optional Chaining, i.e. `[match?.params]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a `useEffect` with dependency on the route match param is sufficient for issuing side-effects like refetching relevant data.

The ionic `useIonViewWillEnter` and `useIonViewDidEnter` hooks described [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/lifecycle#guidance-for-each-lifecycle-method) are basically mounting lifecycle hooks, and don't seem like they'd trigger if you're already on a view and only changing URL path parameters. Move the logic to a `useEffect` hook which is called when component mounts ***and*** when any of its specified dependencies update.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // business logic to handle name param changes
}, [match.params.name]);
```

If the match params is ever undefined then you can use Optional Chaining operator to guard against null/undefined object accesses.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // business logic to handle name param changes
}, [match?.params?.name]);
```

### Update

It seems the `useIonViewWillEnter` and `useIonViewDidEnter` hooks ***do*** also take dependency arrays and internally implement a `useEffect` hook. (*should have dug a bit more previously*)

[Source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/7315e0157b917d2e3586c64f8082026827812943/packages/react/src/lifecycle/hooks.ts)

> ```
> export const useIonViewWillEnter = (callback: LifeCycleCallback, deps: any[] = []) => {
>   const context = useContext(IonLifeCycleContext);
>   const id = useRef<number | undefined>();
>   id.current = id.current || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
>   useEffect(() => {
>     callback.id = id.current!;
>     context.onIonViewWillEnter(callback);
>   }, deps);
> };
>
> export const useIonViewDidEnter = (callback: LifeCycleCallback, deps: any[] = []) => {
>   const context = useContext(IonLifeCycleContext);
>   const id = useRef<number | undefined>();
>   id.current = id.current || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
>   useEffect(() => {
>     callback.id = id.current!;
>     context.onIonViewDidEnter(callback);
>   }, deps);
> };
> ```

The `useEffect` hook isn't necessary then.

```
useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  // business logic to handle name param changes
}, [match?.params?.name]);
```

Comment: I may add that the same params for useEffect applies to IonViewWill/Did enter like so:

```
useIonViewDidEnter(()=>{
// actions
}, [match?.params?.name])
```

Comment: @tomigeme Nice! I should have dug a little deeper, sorry.